# Why does ESRI-Dojo Application build includes dgrid and dgrid1 packages

Tags: dojo, dgrid, esri-javascript-api

I am working on creating an Web Application using ESRI JavaScript API v 3.23 and Dojo v 1.13.

For setting up the application build, I am referring the below link

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/inside_bower_custom_builds.html

After doing npm install, I can see two folders (dojo packages) for dgrid (one is dgrid and other is dgrid1)

I wanted to know what is the difference between dgrid and dgrid1 packages ?

Secondly, if I just want to install the contents of dgrid1 package, what configuration change is needed in bower to do that.

Comment: I found that two dgrid packages have different version, dgrid package has version is 0.3.17 and dgrid1 package is having version 1.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 3.23 of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript include:
    - dgrid version 1.2.1 (since version 3.22), and
    - dgrid version 0.3.17 (since version 3.13)

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/whats_new.html

You'll need both dgrid and dgrid1 packages installed.